# How to close the default tab of ASP.NET application

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

I've a single(default) page asp.net web application with some textbox and a submit button.
*On click of submit button* I wish to run some of my logic and then the **tab in which my web page is loaded should be closed.**

I know that one can open a new tab with the help of `window.open()` and then close the same using `window.close()` but in my case it's the default page which needs to be closed.

So is there a way to open the default page using `window.open()` or
any other way by which I could **close the tab in which my web page is loaded.**

Comment: `window.close()` close active tab. what will happen when you use this code?

Comment: `window.close()` closes the window _only if you have opened the window using `window.open()`_ otherwise of no use.

Answer (score 0):

this block code will end process of your chrome browser and close tab:

```
      foreach (var ie in Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome"))
      {
          try
          {
              ie.Kill();
          }
          catch { }
      }
```

use it in your controller. I hope it's worked.

Comment: This will only try to kill the chrome process on the server?

Comment: yes but if you use another browser you can write its name insist of chrome for example :`Process.GetProcessesByName("firefox")`

Comment: I know, but since OP is talking about a web application, the server will never be able to close a client-side browser window.

Comment: I understand what you say but `.Kill()` ends this active process.and when it has been ended browser tab automatically will close.